# Jupyter Notebooks Located In Remote Github Repository Doesn't Work

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook

This is a problem that I find quite perplexing. I usually use Jupyter Notebook as literally a notebook to run snippets of code along the main code files. However, I've noticed that whenever I try to use Notebooks that are inside a remote Git repository, they don't work. I can't run anything and the Notebook gets stuck on the hourglass icon thing.

This isn't a problem for other Notebooks that I have locally on my computer.

Has anyone experienced the same, and if so how did you solve it? Is it normally not a good idea to keep Jupyter Notebooks inside remote Git repos?